# When PHP Counter reaches x visitor limit, redirect to new page

Tags: php, timer, count, visitors

I am very new to this, It s for a project for school. (I don t know php, only playing with flash for design)

I am using a php code loaded in my flash webpage to count the number of visitors. What do I have to add for when the counter reaches a X number of visitors to redirect to different page or **part of the flash webpage**)
btw it has an output I think, as it sends the number of visitors to be showed on the website thru a Dynamic Text

```
<?     
    $filename = "PHPCounter.txt"; 
    $fp = fopen( $filename,"r");             
    $Old = fread($fp, 100);
    fclose( $fp );
    $Old = split ("=", $Old, 5);        
    $NewCount = $Old[1] + '1';        
    $New = "myCount=$NewCount";        
    $fp = fopen( $filename,"w+");         
    if (flock($fp, 2)) { 
      fwrite($fp, $New, 100);
    }         
    fclose( $fp );

    print "myCount=$NewCount";     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to redirect to a new page:

```
header("Location: newpage.php");
```

Make sure there is no output to the browser before this function happens, otherwise it won't work.

So after X number of views (I've used 100 as an example):

```
if ($NewCount >= 100) {
  header("Location: newpage.php");
  exit();
}
```

Not sure how you'd go about directing it to a specific part of the flash, don't know if thats even possible. My flash isn't really up to scratch, sorry.

Comment: excuse my noobness, where do I add these lines? into the PHPcounter.php file ?

Comment: Yeah, if the code above is all that is in your file, then add it just underneath the "fclose( $fp );" line, but before the "print ..." line.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response! i added the lines but when i refresh the page until it reaches my set limit, it doesn't redirect. do i have to add the first line also (the one with header("Location: newpage.php")) ?

Comment: does it give any output at all? An error? The header("Location... code is within the 2nd block of code I gave anyway, so no need to include it twice.

Try removing the if statement around it, see if it redirects then. If it does then there must be an issue with your $NewCount variable.

Comment: it has an output I think, as it sends the number of visitors to be showed on the website thru a Dynamic Text.